# String concatenation memory usage in C#

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

Is this two patterns of String Concatenation consume same amount of memory?

```
//Method 1
String testString = "Test " + " string " + " content";

//Method 2
String testString = "Test ";
testString = testString + " string ";
testString = testString + " content";
```

Should we avoid both of these methods and use `StringBuilder` class ?

Comment: The first will be *compiled* down to a single string, so the second example is the only one that will actually result in run-time concatenation.

Comment: Does it really matter? ;) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: I could to choose `.Format()` or `StringBuilder` according to context. The dana's links have very good examples. And as there has mentioned,you will see me never using `+` operator on strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 would result in more allocation of memory, string object shall be created to store the following combinations

```
1) "Test "
2) " String"
3) "Test string"
4) " Content"
5) "Test String Content"
```

Where in case of Method 1 just one string shall be created

```
1) "Test string Content"
```

Method 1 is should be preferred among these two methods

`StringBuilder` class is more efficient when you need to build a string that involves combining many string values.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, StringBuilder is the better option.
In all the other cases you describe you are creating multiple new strings since strings are  immutable in C# and can't be changed. This causes c# to simulate changes to strings by creating new strings.

Method one could be converted to a single string. There is no need to concatenate fixed substrings to build the string

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,it is a big difference between these two method.
After building,in method 1,string testString = "Test  string  content",
but in method 2,string testString = "Test  ",
in run-time,they are also different,in method 1,string testString just refrence to an address in immutable,but in method 2,the clr allocate the new memory in heap and combine the strings together.
And i think StringBuilder is a good way for combining string frequently.